# Intersection of QuerySet and list of objects

Tags: django, django-orm

Assume that I have a query set of Product model.

```
products_qs = Product.objects.filter(...)
products_list = [<Product 1>, <Product 5>]
```

How can I detect intersection of products_qs and products_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Product`s in the `product_list` have a primary key, you can filter with:

```
products_qs.filter(pk__in=[product.pk for product in product_list])
```

This will do the filtering at the database side. If the queryset is *not* loaded into memory, this will be more efficient, since you will only retrieve `Product`s from the database that are in the intersection.

That being said, a list of model objects typically means there is something wrong with the code, only in certain cases, for example preparing a list of objects to be created or updated, using a list makes sense. A `QuerySet` has the advantage that there is an API to further filter the collection down, order it, etc. and is lazy, hence it does not load the items *eagerly*.